# Reload Rails 3 initializer in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a Rails 3 app where users can select one of a number of templates and build a little website. I'm trying to initialize all of the available templates when the application starts. That's essentially a file that let's me define them all, then calls `Template.add(template)` for each one of them, which in turn stores them in `@@templates` and I can access them via `Template.find(name)`.

The problem is that in development mode, the initializer I have making the calls to `Template.add` are getting loaded on the first request, then wiped out on `reload!`. I've read about `config.to_prepare`, but it isn't working for me, likely because I'm requiring the templates like this:

```
# template config at app/templates/template_name/template_name.rb
path = File.expand_path(Rails.root + 'app/templates')
Dir[File.join(path, '/*')].each do |template|
  name = File.basename(template)
  require File.join(path, name, "#{name}.rb")
end
```

What can I do to either reload these files after `reload!` or keep them from getting trashed at all? Also, if you have a recommendation for a better way to handle this, I'm all ears. I'm still getting my footing with Rails, especially in regards to configuration stuff.

*I'm temporarily avoiding this problem by loading the data in the class. Save me from this ugly, non-modular nastiness.*

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. So just a suggestion: why don't you autoload your files? http://hemju.com/2010/09/22/rails-3-quicktip-autoload-lib-directory-including-all-subdirectories/

Comment: Lack of familiarity with the process, really, but it doesn't solve my problem anyways. The Template model is getting reloaded on every request (cache_classes = false in development) and my template files won't be reloaded, so on the second request there aren't any template's "registered" with the Template model.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you think this is not working with to_prepare?

Comment: This might be worth a look, as it has alot of detail about the initialization process:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Comment: When I used `to_prepare` everything loaded on the first run through, and then not again afterward. I would imagine it's because I was using `require` instead of `load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ought to be able to do this with `config.to_prepare` if you move your calls to `Template.add` out of the `template_name.rb` files (I am assume that is where they are now), and into your loading code, just after the `require`. For example, consider adding this class method to your Template class, and then maybe even calling it from the class itself when it first gets loaded:

```
class Template
  def self.load_all
    # template config at app/templates/template_name/template_name.rb
    path = File.expand_path(Rails.root + 'app/templates')
    Dir[File.join(path, '/*')].each do |template|
      name = File.basename(template)
      require File.join(path, name, "#{name}.rb")

      # Register the template even if the class itself is already loaded.
      Template.add(name)
    end
  end

  # Initially load all templates.
  Template.load_all
end
```

Then remove the `Template.add(name)` code from the `template_name.rb` files where they are registering themselves. (Again, I am assuming this is where that currently happens - I am not quite clear on this from your original post.) Or perhaps you just want to make sure `Template.add` is idempotent and silently discards duplicates.

Lastly, add the following to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Template.load_all
end
```

That will reload all your templates after the `Template` class reloads.

I haven't tried this, but with the call to `Template.load_all` I suggested at the end of the `Template` class, you may not even need the `config.to_prepare` part.

Comment: I didn't know about `config.to_prepare` when I had this issue and haven't thought much about it since I posted this, but I *think* this will work quite well for me. I'll give it a go when I have time and accept if so.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the lookup of template names to their files in a memory store like memcached or Redis, or even in the database.  The initializer could load up the memory store or ensure that the database is up to date with all the values, and then  `Template.find` could just look to the store to see where the files are, or even just get the class name if they are already going to be loaded.  Simply seeing if the class name is defined can tell you if you need to require the template file or just go ahead and create your new instance.

Basically store `@@templates` outside of the rails process memory, or at least enough information that you could build the parts of `@@templates` that you need on the fly.

Comment: Hmm. I definitely don't want to introduce any additional dependencies into the application needlessly. I *was* using ActiveRecord, but I don't like the idea of altering the database when the application starts; I feel like there could wind up an issue if two dynos (I'm on Heroku) fire up at the same time.